# Script div show/hide slide animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, slide

I have this script:

```
// <![CDATA[
function showHide() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("last-edition");
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
      }
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
}
// ]]>
```

And the animation made by it is show/hide, simple but I would like to create a slide one if possible. How do I make it?

Example: http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/index/tmt/0-20
The 2012 is where script is acting.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I use jQuery.

Comment: Consider using jQuery, which can do this in one line.

Comment: There must be like literally hundreds of libraries and examples on the net for sliding animation.

Comment: You've included the jQuery tag in the question, but haven't used jQuery - check out the documentation http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/

Comment: problem is that i'm not that good at scripting...don't know how to write what i need, only in basic stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short jQuery version of your script will be like this:

```
function showHide() {
    $('#last-edition').slideToggle();
}
```

Consider having a look at [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/). It's well-written.

As this function consists only of one line - it's pretty useless...

If you are trying to make this block appear/disappear on certain user interactions - then simply omit the function declaration. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/Qzwme/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery:

```
$("#last-edition").show("slow");
```

instead of `ele.style.display = "block";`

and

```
$("#last-edition").hide("slow");
```

instead of `ele.style.display = "none";`

Comment: works, but skip405 answer is shorter, both answers are right tho, thank you!